# Pomegranate juice ceviche

Tags: fish, acidity, ceviche, pomegranate

I want to make a ceviche and although the 'traditional' acids are lemon and lime, I have a desire to use pomegranate juice but I'm concerned that the pH is too low to denature the proteins in the fish. Does anyone know if pomegranate juice just isn't acidic enough or should I just marinade for longer? I haven't been able to find any recipes using it, is this a sign?

- Pomegranate pH 2.93 - 3.20
- Lime pH 2.00 - 2.80
- Lemon Juice pH 2.00 - 2.60

[pH Source](http://www.foodscience.caes.uga.edu/extension/documents/fdaapproximatephoffoodslacf-phs.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a combination of pomegranate juice and lemon juice?

A [recipe on the POM web site](http://www.pomwonderful.com/pomegranate-recipes/Grapefruit-Pomegranate-Ceviche/) uses grapefruit juice with pomegranate juice.

A quick search reveals that most (all) ceviches that use pomegranate juice also use another acid (lemon, lime, grapefruit).

If it were me, I'd try using only pomegranate juice only on a small batch of fish a check how it goes.